# Incremented h:mm:ss Timer in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to create a new column that counts up in the h:mm:ss format such that `E2 displays 0:00:00, E3 displays 0:00:01 ... E62 displays 0:01:00` and so forth.

I have tried inputting a properly formatted count in the first ~5 rows of the column and then dragging it down through the range I want but Excel cannot seem to understand that I want the count to increment in seconds.

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to format the column as time (`hh:mm:ss`), then set every element to `=(ROW()-2)/86400`.

This works because times are stored as fractions of a day, which has 86400 seconds in it. The `=ROW()` function returns the current row.

Comment: This worked and provides a very logical yet simple solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

So in E3 put:

```
=E2+TIME(0,0,1)
```

Then copy down.  It will add one second to the value above it.

[image]

Comment: I have my cells formatted at h:mm:ss and for some reason when I put `0:00:00` in E2 and then `=E2+TIME(0,0,1)` in E3 and then copy down it results in `0:00:10` instead of `0:00:01`.